# qt-running query

Tags: c++, sql, qt

in my program i have two specific query, if the first query is successfully executed then second query must also be executed. i am wondering that if the first query is executed and something happens like lost internet connection or closing the program before the second query is ran, in that case what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute both queries as one transaction. To do this, call [QSqlDatabase::transaction()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#transaction) just before executing the first query. This will initiate the transaction. Then proceed to execute your second query.

If your second query succeeds as well,  then call [QSqlDatabase::commit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#commit). If your second query fails for whatever reason, you could call [QSqlDatabase::rollback()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#rollback), and that should rollback the changes made by your first query as well.

Comment: if first query is executed successfully and 2nd query is failed and rollback is also failed then what happens? and if both query is successfully executed and commit is failed then what happens?

Comment: Have you had a chance to click the links and read the documentation? There seem to be a way to find out why commit failed, for example.

Comment: it only tells about select is it same for update or insert??